# Using images as form backgrounds?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image, visual-studio, gdi

If I wanted to create a resizable form from an image would I have to use a vector image?

An example would be Photoshop. It can be resized and it maintains the rounded corners and also the outer edge without making it look distorted and stretched.

I know simple patterns can be tiled in the background, but trying to have perfect rounded corners is a hard task. How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `OnPaint` method for your form and draw the background yourself in the right size. Since you're drawing primitives (paths, rectangles, ellipses, etc.) it's not a source bitmap that gets scaled and you can adapt to the form's size.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how you would do that. Would the image not be distorted which would cause the corners to get stretched?